# Get list of variable names in a class at run time using Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to get a list of the variables on the current class/form at run time.
What i to do ? I am using delphi 7 and don't have a RTTI to help me, or not ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot dynamically iterate over variables within a class in Delphi 7 (using RTTI or otherwise).

You can use RTTI to access published properties (and procedures/functions which implement any RTTI-enabled interfaces), but that is all.

If you want to iterate over components in a form, this is very easy using the Form's `Components` property.

Comment: I think I expressed myself badly. I need to check if a registry key is a variable name in the same current unit. If there is, I need to pass the value of the registry key for this variable.

Comment: You can't enumerate variables in units @user1937752 - it sounds like you need to find another way to do what you're doing.